# Iterate and search a JSON array for the element in the array

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
response = {
    "items"=>[
        {
            "tags"=>[
                "random"
            ],
            "timestamp"=>12345,
            "storage"=>{
                "url"=>"https://example.com/example",
                "key"=>"mykeys"
            },
            "envelope"=>{

            },
            "log-level"=>"info",
            "id"=>"random_id_test_1",
            "campaigns"=>[

            ],
            "user-variables"=>{

            },
            "flags"=>{
                "is-test-mode"=>false
            },
            "message"=>{
                "headers"=>{
                    "to"=>"random@example.com",
                    "message-id"=>"foobar@example.com",
                    "from"=>"noreply@example.com",
                    "subject"=>"new subject"
                },
                "attachments"=>[

                ],
                "recipients"=>[
                    "result@example.com"
                ],
                "size"=>4444
            },
            "event"=>"stored"
        },
        {
            "tags"=>[
                "flowerPower"
            ],
            "timestamp"=>567890,
            "storage"=>{
                "url"=>"https://yahoo.com",
                "key"=>"some_really_cool_keys_go_here"
            },
            "envelope"=>{

            },
            "log-level"=>"info",
            "id"=>"some_really_cool_ids_go_here",
            "campaigns"=>[

            ],
            "user-variables"=>{

            },
            "flags"=>{
                "is-test-mode"=>false
            },
            "message"=>{
                "headers"=>{
                    "to"=>"another_great@example.com",
                    "message-id"=>"email_id@example.com",
                    "from"=>"from@example.com",
                    "subject"=>"email_looks_good"
                },
                "attachments"=>[

                ],
                "recipients"=>[
                    "example@example.com"
                ],
                "size"=>2222
            },
            "event"=>"stored"

        }]
}
```

I am trying to obtain the `"storage"` `"url"` based on the `"to"` email.
How do I iterate through this array where `x` is just the element in the array

```
response['items'][x]["message"]["headers"]["to"]
```

Once I find the specific email that I need, it will stop and return the value of `x` which is the element number.
I was going to use that value for `x` and call `response['items'][x]['storage']['url']`
which will return the string for the URL.

I thought about doing this but there's gotta be a better way:

```
x = 0
user_email = another_great@example.com
while user_email != response['items'][x]["message"]["headers"]["to"] do
  x+=1
  value = x
  puts value
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important to strip data to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that only slows our ability to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target = 
  response['items'].detect do |i| 
    i['message']['headers']['to'] == 'another_great@example.com'
  end
```

then

```
target['storage']['url']
```

Comment: thanks, I was able to verify that in irb. I was ripping my hair out trying everything in irb wasn't working. I learned a new method today. "detect" Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure the OP didn't want `i['message']['headers'].key?('to')`? Do we know that `target != nil`?

Comment: Are you sure that's the same question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - yeah, doing that will make the code more robust. Ideally, it should never be nil. But you never know. if it is nil it won't be too catastrophic. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @satoru - could i use a regex? (trying to do domain matching:
i['message']['headers']['to'] == /example.com/

Comment: @adbarads You can replace `==` with `=~` to match regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is another option by creating Hash with key of `to's email`. And on basis of it fetch required information like this:

```
email_hash = Hash.new
response["items"].each do |i|
   email_hash[i["message"]["headers"]["to"]] = i
end
```

Now if you want to fetch `"storage"` `"url"` then simply do:

```
user_email = "another_great@example.com"
puts email_hash[user_email]["storage"]["url"] if email_hash[user_email]

#=> "https://yahoo.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as @Satoru suggested. As a suggestion, if you use case involves complex queries on json data (more complex than this), then you can store your data in mongodb, and can elegantly query anything.